# Алгоритм для преобразования диапазона номеров в регулярное выражение

Tags: алгоритм, регулярные-выражения, любой-язык

Не знаю, насколько правильно выглядит сам заголовок, но подробнее опишу здесь.

Итак, суть такова: есть, к примеру, некий диапазон и пара условий:

- `$start` и `$end` всегда имеют одинаковую символьную длину (хотя это и не столь важно);
- И если есть диапазон, включающий в себя элемент `555123456` (длина `9` символов), то нет никакого другого диапазона, который включал бы в себя номер, превосходящий по длине уже имеющийся и начинающийся с `555` - т.е. номер 555123456**7** (длина - 10 символов) не существует по определению.
- Последние цифры в `$start` и `$end` равняются `0` и `9` соответственно, что тоже облегчает задачу.

Т.е. *(здесь и далее пишу условно, без привязки к каким-либо языку программирования или стандарту `regexp`)*

```
555000000 - 555999999 // Т.е. 555*
666000000 - 666999999 // Т.е. 666*

5550000000 - 5559999999 // Не существует в списке диапазонов по определению задачи, игнорируем.
6660000000 - 6669999999 // Не существует в списке диапазонов по определению задачи, игнорируем.
```

Иными словами: если задан 555000000 - 555999999, то нет 555000000**0** - 555999999**9**

Возьмем, например

```
555000000 - 555999999
```

Задача: преобразовать в `555*`. С указанным примером разобраться несложно - необходимо отнять `$start` от `$end`, чтобы получить некую переменную `$result`, которая равна `999999`. Затем использовать значение результата операции `$result.length()` по отношению к, скажем, `$start`, чтобы получить строку `555*`

```
$shortrec = substr($start,0,-strlen($result)) . "*";
```

Но если диапазон выглядит как

```
777120000 - 777259999
```

то разница будет иметь значение `139999`. Здесь сложнее, но тоже понятно - помимо отчасти указанного выше, сравниваем позиции `0` и `9` в обеих переменных, "выходим" на `12` и дополнительно обрабатываем `12`, наращивая его `13` раз и получая в цикле следующую последовательность:

```
77712*
77713*
77714*
...
77725*
```

Но как быть, если есть диапазон,

```
888125120 - 888959599
```

(здесь вспомним облегчающее логику условие номер `3`, чтобы не оперировать выражением типа `[5-9]`, если бы `$start` равнялся бы 88812512**5**) для которого необходимо получить

```
88812512*
8882*
8883*
...
8888*

88890*
88891*
88892*
...
88894*

888950*
888951*
888952*
...
888958*

8889590*
8889591*
8889592*
...
8889595*
```

- Прошу рассудить - следую ли я с самого начала правильной логике или нет?
- И есть ли некоторое универсальное решение (алгоритм) для подобных задач?
- Как поступили бы вы?

P.S. Язык программирования не важен - важен сам подход и алгоритм. Надеюсь, не сломал читающему мозг, но задача не из учебных, а самая что ни на есть настоящая. Так что если есть идеи, буду весьма признателен.

Comment: 88812512\* - недостаточно. Придется рассмотреть еще 8881252\*\*, 888126\*\*\*, 88813\*\*\*\*...

Comment: @gecube Верно, спасибо. Я просто на скорую руку писал. Просто сама цель, самое главное, понятна.

Comment: А кстати, для чего вам регулярное выражение? Не проще ли просто сравнить число с верхней и нижней границей?

Comment: Во-первых, всем огромное спасибо за проявленное внимание, во-вторых хочу извиниться за поздний ответ - непредвиденные обстоятельства в виде нежданной испорченной трубы водопровода и последующего небольшого ремонта в квартире. Соответственно не мог рассмотреть подробно в эти дни все ответы и комментарии :)

Comment: @VladD Дело в том, что есть некоторая старая система, которая оперирует именно таким образом, причем проверяет еще и уникальность номера, чтобы предотвратить занесение малого диапазона, к примеру, 5550100-5550199, в уже имеющийся больший 5550000-5559999. Новая же система имеет интерфейс, который требует именно регулярки. Поэтому возникла необходимость преобразования и экспорта данных. 
Хотя мне удалось переубедить вендора и предоставить интерфейс совместимости для использования диапазонов. Поэтому вопрос решен в мою пользу, а сам вопрос здесь переходит в категорию тематических и интересных :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Писать алгоритм генерации будем для частного случая - когда число знаков у нижней и верхней границы одинаковы. Если же число знаков разное, то исходный диапазон будет разбит на 3 диапазона:

1. от минимальной границы до максимального числа с таким же числом цифр
2. все полные диапазоны чисел, которые не были затронуты границами
3. от минимального числа с таким же числом цифр, как у максимальной границы, до максимальной границы

На примере понятнее, что все это обозначает. Исходный диапазон `14-123456` разбиваем на три диапазона `14-99, 100-99999, 100000-123456`.
Если присутствует второй диапазон, то он задается простым выражением `\d{n,m}`, первый и второй диапазон нужно генерировать отдельно и в границах этих диапазонов всегда одинаковое количество знаков, а значит применим основной алгоритм генерации, а затем объединим эти 3 диапазона альтернативой.

**Основной алгоритм для диапазонов с одинаковым количеством цифр**

1. Попытаемся найти общую часть для верхней и нижней границы. Например в диапазоне `1234-1278` можно вынести `12` как обычные символы.
2. Начнем просмотр границ слева-направо. Для примера диапазон `1234-5678`
3. Первые цифры нижней и верхней границ `1` и `5`, поэтому разделим на 3 диапазона: `1234-1999, 2000-4999, 5000-5678`, то есть как бы выделим середину, которую можно представить как `[2-4]\d{3}`
4. Оставшиеся два диапазона обработаем по тому же самому алгоритму. Например для `1234-1999` сперва вынесем цифру 1 как общую. Диапазон `234-999` разобьем на 2 диапазона `234-299, 300-999`
5. И так далее для всех диапазонов, которые появятся в ходе разбиения на составные диапазоны.

Кода безумно много, но зато можно запустить и потестировать.

```js
$( document ).ready( function() {
  $( "#rangeLeft, #rangeRight" ).keydown( function() {
    clearDisplay();
  } );
  $( "#run" ).click( function() {
    clearDisplay();
    var rangeLeft = $( "#rangeLeft" ).val();
    var rangeRight = $( "#rangeRight" ).val();
    if ( ! checkRanges( rangeLeft,  rangeRight ) ) return;
    $( "#result" ).append( generateFullRegExp(rangeLeft, rangeRight)+"<BR/>" );
    $( "#test" ).show();
  } );
  $( "#test" ).click( function() {
    var rangeLeft = $( "#rangeLeft" ).val();
    var rangeRight = $( "#rangeRight" ).val();
    var re = new RegExp( "^"+generateFullRegExp(rangeLeft, rangeRight)+"$" );
    for( var i=Math.pow( 10, rangeLeft.length-1 ); i<Math.pow( 10, rangeRight.length); i++ ) {
      if ( re.test( i+"" ) && ( i<parseInt(rangeLeft) || i>parseInt(rangeRight) ) ) $( "#result" ).append( "Тест провален на: " + i+"<BR/>" );
      if ( !re.test( i+"" ) && ( i>parseInt(rangeLeft) && i<parseInt(rangeRight) ) ) $( "#result" ).append( "Тест провален на: " + i+"<BR/>" );
    };
    $( "#result" ).append( "Тест пройден от "+Math.pow( 10, rangeLeft.length-1 )+" до "+i+"<BR/>" );
  } );
} );

function checkRanges( rangeLeft, rangeRight ) {
  if ( /\D/.test( rangeLeft ) || /\D/.test( rangeRight ) ) {
    $( "#result" ).append( "Введите два числа<BR/>" );
    return false;
  };
  rangeLeft = parseInt( rangeLeft );
  rangeRight = parseInt( rangeRight );
  if ( isNaN( rangeLeft ) || isNaN( rangeRight ) ) $( "#result" ).append( "Не указаны границы диапазонов<BR/>" );
  if ( rangeLeft < 0 ) $( "#result" ).append( "Левая граница меньше 0<BR/>" );
  if ( rangeRight < 0 ) $( "#result" ).append( "Правая граница меньше 0<BR/>" );
  if ( rangeLeft > rangeRight ) $( "#result" ).append( "Левая граница больше правой границы<BR/>" );
  return( !(
    rangeLeft < 0 ||
    rangeRight < 0 ||
    rangeLeft > rangeRight ||
    isNaN( rangeLeft ) ||
    isNaN( rangeRight )
  ) );
};

function maxBeginStr( str1, str2 ) {
  var res = /^(.*)[^-]*\-\1/.exec( str1 + "-" + str2 );
  return res ? res[1] : "";
};

function midDiap( start, end ){
  var st0int = parseInt( start[0] );
  var en0int = parseInt( end[0] );
  if ( st0int+1 == en0int ) {
    var res = end[0];
  } else {
   if ( st0int == en0int-2 ) {
    res=( st0int+1 )+"";
   } else {
    res="["+( st0int+1 )+"-"+(en0int-1)+"]";
   };
  };
  if ( start.length == 1 ) return res;
  return res+"\\d{"+(start.length-1)+"}";
};

function lowDiap( num, pos ) {
  var res = num.substr(0, pos);
  var highRange = parseInt( num[pos] )-1;
  if ( highRange == -1 && pos == num.length-1 ) return num;
  if ( highRange == -1 ) return null; // выражение можно не включать
  if ( pos == num.length-1 ) highRange++;
  res += "[0-"+highRange+"]";
  if ( num.length != pos+1 ){
    res += "\\d{"+(num.length-pos-1)+"}";
  }
  return res;
};

function highDiap( num, pos ) {
  var res = num.substr(0, pos);
  var lowRange = parseInt( num[pos] )+1;
  if ( lowRange==10 && pos == num.length-1 ) return num;
  if ( lowRange==10 ) return null; // выражение можно не включать
  if ( pos == num.length-1 ) lowRange--;
  res += "["+lowRange+"-9]";
  if ( num.length != pos+1 ){
    res += "\\d{"+( num.length -pos-1)+"}";
  }
  return res;
};

function getRegExp( start, end ) {
    if ( start.length != end.length ) return "Invalid input";
    var res= maxBeginStr( start, end );
    start= start.substr( res.length ); 
    end  = end.substr( res.length );
    if ( start.length  == 0 ) return res;
    var st0int = parseInt( start[0] );
    var en0int = parseInt( end[0] );
    var resArr= Array(); 
    if ( start.length > 1 ) {
      if ( st0int != en0int-1 ) {
        resArr.push( midDiap( start, end) );
      }
      for ( var i=1; i<end.length; i++ ) {
        var miniRe = lowDiap( end, i );
        if ( miniRe != null ) {
          resArr.push( miniRe );
        }
        miniRe = highDiap( start, i );
        if ( miniRe != null) {
          resArr.push( miniRe );
        }
      }
    } else {
      resArr.push( "["+start+"-"+end+"]" );
    };
    return res+"(?:"+resArr.join("|")+")";
};

function generateFullRegExp( rangeLeft, rangeRight ) {
  if ( rangeLeft.length == rangeRight.length ) {
    return getRegExp( rangeLeft, rangeRight ); 
  };
  var resArr = Array();
  resArr.push( getRegExp( rangeLeft, "9".repeat( rangeLeft.length ) ) );
  if ( rangeRight.length - rangeLeft.length > 1 ) resArr.push( ("\\d{"+(rangeLeft.length+1)+","+(rangeRight.length-1)+"}").replace(/(\d+),\1/, "$1") );
  resArr.push( getRegExp( "1"+"0".repeat( rangeRight.length-1 ), rangeRight ) );
  return "(?:"+resArr.join("|")+")";
};

function clearDisplay() {
  $( "#result" ).html( "" );
  $( "#test" ).hide();
};
```

```css
#test { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <BODY>
    <INPUT id="rangeLeft" value=1234 /> - <INPUT id="rangeRight" value=4567 />
    <BR/>
    <BUTTON id="run">Генерировать</BUTTON>
    <PRE id="result" ></PRE>
    <BUTTON id="test">Проверить</BUTTON>
  </BODY>
```

**Существующий недочет**
Для диапазона `10-29` и.т.п. сгенерируется избыточное выражение `(?:2[0-9]|1[0-9])`

Comment: Благодарю! Подход очень осмыслен и сложен (хотя и сама постановка задачи сложная).

Comment: Я несколько переделал ваш код, объединив его с [to-regex-range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-regex-range) и добавив несколько дополнительных параметров, и опубликовал [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67502416/3832970).

Answer (score 7):

Т.к. границы диапозонов имеют одинаковую разрядность, то можно использовать такой способ преобразования диапозона в регулярку - это поразрядное сравнение границ и генерации ретроспективных проверок на все предыдущие разряды относительно текущей позиции.

Для диапозона 813 - 895 выражение будет например таким:

```
8[1-9](?:(?<=1)[3-9]|(?<=[2-8])[0-9]|(?<=9)[0-5])
```

Обратите внимание, что здесь рассматривается три случая относительно среднего разряда:

1. Значение равно нижней границе - 1, значит текущее значение не может быть меньше 3.
2. Значение между нижней и верхней границами, значит текущее значение может быть любой цифрой.
3. Значение равно верхней границе - 9, значит текущее значение не может быть больше 5.

Чем выше разрядность, тем сложнее получится конечное регулярное выражение, т.к. для каждого младшего разряда нужно выполнять ретроспективные проверки для всех старших разрядов.

Comment: Благодарю - очень интересно было рассмотреть логику!

Answer (score 6):

Я бы сделал рекурсивный спуск: (C#)

```cs
IEnumerable<string> GetPatterns(string start, string end)
{
    if (start.Length == 0)
    {
        yield return "";
        yield break;
    }
    var startPrefix = start.Substring(0, start.Length - 1);
    var endPrefix = end.Substring(0, end.Length - 1);

    var startSuffix = start.Last();
    var endSuffix = end.Last();

    var rec = GetPatterns(startPrefix, endPrefix).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < rec.Count; i++)
    {
        char startDigit = (i == 0) ? startSuffix : '0';
        char endDigit = (i == rec.Count - 1) ? endSuffix : '9';

        if (startDigit == '0' && endDigit == '9')
        {
            yield return rec[i] + '*';
        }
        else
        {
            for (var digit = startDigit; digit <= endDigit; digit++)
                yield return rec[i] + digit;
        }
    }
}
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/xihhpr

Обратите внимание на результат для промежутка `5050000-5959999` — вам надо такое, или нет?

Comment: Еще раз спасибо - очень правильный подход, да еще и на C# - как раз именно его я собирался использовать для рабочей версии. Плюсую всем, так как все ответы заслуживают благодарности и говорят о замечательном логическом мышлении.

Comment: @void: спасибо!