# Регулярное выражение для поиска строк, содержащих числа от 1 до 10

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения

Помогите доделать регулярку, которая проверяет строку на то, чтобы в ней были числа, разделенные ',' в диапазоне от 1 до 10.

Например валидны должны быть такие строки:

1

2,3,4

10

Пробовал так:

```
^[1-10](,[1-10])*$
```

но это не работает.

Comment: @Akina не помогло.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Алгоритм для преобразования диапазона номеров в регулярное выражение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/245209/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строка состоит из чисел, разделенных символом ","

шаблон числа `10|[1-9]`

Общий шаблон

```
^(10|[1-9])(,(10|[1-9]))*$
```

Comment: по этому выражению строка "2,500" является валидной, хотя это не правильно.

Comment: @IAMLERNCSHARP  Просто до 10 это цифры, а не числа. Исправил.

Comment: @because спасибо