# Настройка регулярного выражения для Validator (диапазон от -99 до +99). Проблема с переходом через 0

Tags: регулярные-выражения, qt, express-validator

Голову сломал с ребусом как запретить писать "-0"
То-есть нужен интервал для этажа здания -99....-1....0.....1....99

```
lineEdit_level->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("^([1-9]|-)([0-9])"), this));
```

Помогите кто может с этой шахматной партией.

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так можно:

```
"^(-?[1-9][0-9]?|0)"
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать

```
^(-?(0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])|0)$
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/p7InB2/2).

Тут `^` и `$` требуют совпадения *целой строки*, в которая должна состоять из необязательного минуса (`-?`), за которым следует необязательный символ `0` + любая цифра, отличная от нуля (`0?[1-9]`) или цифры, отличной от нуля, за которой должна следовать любая цифра (`[1-9][0-9]`), или нуля (`0`).

Другой вариант: использовать простой шаблон вроде `^-?[0-9]{1,2}$`, но исключить совпадение 1-2 нулей перед которыми есть минус:

```
^(?!-0+$)-?[0-9]{1,2}$
```

См. [пример работы этого выражения](https://regex101.com/r/p7InB2/3). Тут негативный блок предварительного просмотра вперёд `(?!-0+$)` исключает совпадения отрицательного нулевого значения, а `-?[0-9]{1,2}` находит число из одной или двух цифр с необязательным минусом спереди (как значение целой строки, см. `^` и `$`).

Если вам нужно сгенерировать регулярное выражение для диапазона положительных целых чисел, вы можете воспользоваться следующим примером кода:

```js
!function(e){if("object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module)module.exports=e();else if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd)define([],e);else{("undefined"!=typeof window?window:"undefined"!=typeof global?global:"undefined"!=typeof self?self:this).toRegexRange=e()}}(function(){return function(){return function e(t,n,r){function i(u,a){if(!n[u]){if(!t[u]){var s="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!a&&s)return s(u,!0);if(o)return o(u,!0);var c=new Error("Cannot find module '"+u+"'");throw c.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",c}var f=n[u]={exports:{}};t[u][0].call(f.exports,function(e){return i(t[u][1][e]||e)},f,f.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[u].exports}for(var o="function"==typeof require&&require,u=0;u<r.length;u++)i(r[u]);return i}}()({1:[function(e,t,n){"use strict";const r=e("is-number"),i=(e,t,n)=>{if(!1===r(e))throw new TypeError("toRegexRange: expected the first argument to be a number");if(void 0===t||e===t)return String(e);if(!1===r(t))throw new TypeError("toRegexRange: expected the second argument to be a number.");let o={relaxZeros:!0,...n};"boolean"==typeof o.strictZeros&&(o.relaxZeros=!1===o.strictZeros);let s=e+":"+t+"="+String(o.relaxZeros)+String(o.shorthand)+String(o.capture)+String(o.wrap);if(i.cache.hasOwnProperty(s))return i.cache[s].result;let c=Math.min(e,t),f=Math.max(e,t);if(1===Math.abs(c-f)){let n=e+"|"+t;return o.capture?`(${n})`:!1===o.wrap?n:`(?:${n})`}let l=h(e)||h(t),d={min:e,max:t,a:c,b:f},p=[],g=[];if(l&&(d.isPadded=l,d.maxLen=String(d.max).length),c<0){g=u(f<0?Math.abs(f):1,Math.abs(c),d,o),c=d.a=0}return f>=0&&(p=u(c,f,d,o)),d.negatives=g,d.positives=p,d.result=function(e,t,n){let r=a(e,t,"-",!1,n)||[],i=a(t,e,"",!1,n)||[],o=a(e,t,"-?",!0,n)||[];return r.concat(o).concat(i).join("|")}(g,p,o),!0===o.capture?d.result=`(${d.result})`:!1!==o.wrap&&p.length+g.length>1&&(d.result=`(?:${d.result})`),i.cache[s]=d,d.result};function o(e,t,n){if(e===t)return{pattern:e,count:[],digits:0};let r=function(e,t){let n=[];for(let r=0;r<e.length;r++)n.push([e[r],t[r]]);return n}(e,t),i=r.length,o="",u=0;for(let e=0;e<i;e++){let[t,i]=r[e];t===i?o+=t:"0"!==t||"9"!==i?o+=p(t,i,n):u++}return u&&(o+=!0===n.shorthand?"\\d":"[0-9]"),{pattern:o,count:[u],digits:i}}function u(e,t,n,r){let i,u=function(e,t){let n=1,r=1,i=f(e,n),o=new Set([t]);for(;e<=i&&i<=t;)o.add(i),i=f(e,n+=1);for(i=l(t+1,r)-1;e<i&&i<=t;)o.add(i),i=l(t+1,r+=1)-1;return(o=[...o]).sort(s),o}(e,t),a=[],c=e;for(let e=0;e<u.length;e++){let t=u[e],s=o(String(c),String(t),r),f="";n.isPadded||!i||i.pattern!==s.pattern?(n.isPadded&&(f=g(t,n,r)),s.string=f+s.pattern+d(s.count),a.push(s),c=t+1,i=s):(i.count.length>1&&i.count.pop(),i.count.push(s.count[0]),i.string=i.pattern+d(i.count),c=t+1)}return a}function a(e,t,n,r,i){let o=[];for(let i of e){let{string:e}=i;r||c(t,"string",e)||o.push(n+e),r&&c(t,"string",e)&&o.push(n+e)}return o}function s(e,t){return e>t?1:t>e?-1:0}function c(e,t,n){return e.some(e=>e[t]===n)}function f(e,t){return Number(String(e).slice(0,-t)+"9".repeat(t))}function l(e,t){return e-e%Math.pow(10,t)}function d(e){let[t=0,n=""]=e;return n||t>1?`{${t+(n?","+n:"")}}`:""}function p(e,t,n){return`[${e}${t-e==1?"":"-"}${t}]`}function h(e){return/^-?(0+)\d/.test(e)}function g(e,t,n){if(!t.isPadded)return e;let r=Math.abs(t.maxLen-String(e).length),i=!1!==n.relaxZeros;switch(r){case 0:return"";case 1:return i?"0?":"0";case 2:return i?"0{0,2}":"00";default:return i?`0{0,${r}}`:`0{${r}}`}}i.cache={},i.clearCache=(()=>i.cache={}),t.exports=i},{"is-number":2}],2:[function(e,t,n){"use strict";t.exports=function(e){return"number"==typeof e?e-e==0:"string"==typeof e&&""!==e.trim()&&(Number.isFinite?Number.isFinite(+e):isFinite(+e))}},{}]},{},[1])(1)});


$( document ).ready( function() {
  $( "#rangeLeft, #rangeRight" ).keydown( function() {
    clearDisplay();
  } );
  $( "#run" ).click( function() {
    clearDisplay();
    var rangeLeft = $( "#rangeLeft" ).val();
    var rangeRight = $( "#rangeRight" ).val();
    if ( ! checkRanges( rangeLeft,  rangeRight ) ) return;
    const source = toRegexRange(rangeLeft, rangeRight);
    $( "#result" ).append( source + "<BR/>" );
  } );
} );

function checkRanges( rangeLeft, rangeRight ) {
  if ( /\D/.test( rangeLeft ) || /\D/.test( rangeRight ) ) {
    $( "#result" ).append( "Введите два числа<BR/>" );
    return false;
  };
  rangeLeft = parseInt( rangeLeft );
  rangeRight = parseInt( rangeRight );
  if ( isNaN( rangeLeft ) || isNaN( rangeRight ) ) $( "#result" ).append( "Не указаны границы диапазонов<BR/>" );
  if ( rangeLeft < 0 ) $( "#result" ).append( "Левая граница меньше 0<BR/>" );
  if ( rangeRight < 0 ) $( "#result" ).append( "Правая граница меньше 0<BR/>" );
  if ( rangeLeft > rangeRight ) $( "#result" ).append( "Левая граница больше правой границы<BR/>" );
  return( !(
    rangeLeft < 0 ||
    rangeRight < 0 ||
    rangeLeft > rangeRight ||
    isNaN( rangeLeft ) ||
    isNaN( rangeRight )
  ) );
};

function clearDisplay() {
  $( "#result" ).html( "" );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <BODY>
    <p>
       Код позаимстовоан со страницы <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/245209">Алгоритм для преобразования диапазона номеров в регулярное выражение</a> и <a href="https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-regex-range"><b>to-regex-range</b></a>.
    </p>
    <INPUT id="rangeLeft" value=1 /> - <INPUT id="rangeRight" value=365 />
    <BR/>
    <BUTTON id="run">Создать</BUTTON>
    <PRE id="result" ></PRE>
  </BODY>
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробные пояснения!

Comment: Я кажется начал понимать!  "^(1?[0-7]?|0)" - от 0 до 17 )))))

Comment: Вернее вот так : "^([1-9]?[0-7]?|0)"

Comment: @Anton Я добавил код для автоматического создания регулярного выражения для диапазонов целых положительных чисел.